# appendTo not working in jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add a paragraph to an h2 tag using an id selector.  However, for some reason it's not working properly.  Would someone help me with this?

I have a fiddle I did to try it.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/ahLqZ/4/

Here is my code below:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#cevre h2").appendTo($(this).next("p"));

    })​
```

Comment: You have id's repeating across elements and it is invalid. element id's should be unique

Comment: This is your second question on stackoverflow - please learn how to accept answers ... if you have no idea what I'm talking about [click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170679)

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
$("#cevre h2").each(function() {
     $(this).appendTo($(this).next("p"));
});
```

Uses [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the `h2` elements - then `$(this)` becomes each `h2` element rather then that `document` element

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahLqZ/22/)

**Note** using `appendTo` on an already existing DOM element moves it ... what you probably wanted (maybe not) was this :

```
$("#cevre h2").each(function() {
     $(this).clone().insertAfter($(this).next("p"));
});
```

Uses [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to create a clone of the `h2` first and [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to insert the newly cloned DOM element after the `<p>` element rather then within it ...

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahLqZ/40/)

**Another Note** - its not valid HTML to have duplicate `id` attributes in a single page ... I recommend you change `<div id="cevre">` to `<div class="cevre">` ... your jQuery selector then becomes `$(".cevre h2")`

**Yet another note** - you should cache jQuery objects if they are used multiple times :

```
$(".cevre h2").each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.clone().insertAfter($this.next("p"));
});
```

Comment: Also, the OP probably wants `insertAfter()`, not `appendTo()`.

Comment: @Juhana yes your are probably right .. updated my answer ... thanks

Comment: @thirtydot - this is very ironic - i just posted an answer telling someone to add the `var` keyword to prevent polluting the global namespace - then I do it ....  thanks for the edit ...